# C++ convert from System::DateTime to time_t

Tags: c++, .net, datetime

Hi I want to check if a time in `System::DateTime` is smaller than the current time.
I would like to use this code:

```
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    if (difftime(this->monthCalendar1->SelectionStart, now)) {

    }
```

But the `this->monthCalendar1->SelectionStart` is a `System::DateTime` and the `difftime()` want to use `time_t` so how can I convert a `System::DateTime`object to `time_t`.

Comment: The dupe links covers both to and from cases.

Comment: What's `System::DateTime`, there's no such thing in Standard C++. If it's .NET please specify explicitly